# It Was Noticed That

Tags: meaning-in-context, extraposition

Is this correct use of extraposition:

> **It was noticed** that some students struggled in math.

standard English?  Could it be wrong?

Comment: I find no problem in this sentence.

Comment: Why do you think it might be incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

> It was noticed that some students struggled in math.

The sentence is grammatically correct, though an active form would be more dynamic:

> I noticed that some students struggled in math.

Comment: I got the inspiration from the more common extraposition sentences like  "It was suspected that....", "It was thought that...".  I wonder what other verbs could be used this way.  I do notice that the sentence structure  "it was noticed that ..." is not very common.

Comment: On the contrary the structure is very common, just that using the passive form won’t imply dynamism on your writing in general.

Comment: @meatie - Why did you save that inspiration for a comment, instead of putting it in your original question? Some rather mundane questions on ELL could be made much more interesting if people would just take a little time to elaborate on **why** they are asking.

Answer (score 1):

It may sound like something's wrong with it although the sentence is fine. But, in my opinion,

*"An observation was made..."*
sounds a little better than
*"It was noticed that..."*